# Daily maximum rep exceeded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

I thought that the daily maximum reputation was 200, right?

But today [image]
I got 205. How is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reputation from upvotes is capped at 200. However, some things aren't capped, namely:

1. Bounties.
2. Points from accepted answers (+15 if someone selects your answer)

I see in your case someone selected your answer, thus you got a bonus 15 points. So you could actually get 10 more points still.

Comment: Also, 2 points from accepting an answer to your question don't count towards the rep cap. 100 rep from association bonus don't count either - BUT they also don't count towards Mortarboard series of badges

Answer (score 4):

To add to Pearson's excellent theoretical answer, you can see specifically where you got the rep in 2 ways:

1. Your reputation tab on user page:

   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/19374/shevliaskovic?tab=reputation

   [image]

   Note the **green** square around the last line's rep (15) - that "+15 accept" is what caused you to get 205. Green background indicates that this rep doesn't get capped.
2. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/reputation link.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly as simple as that. If you get +15 *before* you hit 200, it counts toward your 200. If you get +15 *after*, it doesn't. So you could get 20 answer upvotes, 5 accepts, and still only get 200 rep if the accepts all came before the 200 for the day. But if all accepts came after 200 for the day, then you could end up with 275